# Nginx routing root (/)

Tags: routing, nginx

I'm trying to serve an app behind an Nginx router. The app is running on port 3000 and services several routes such as `/api`, `/login`, and `/logout`. I also have static content that I want to show for the `/` route as well as an `/assets` folder. Right now my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /home/app/static;
  index index.html;
  location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
  }
  location ^~ (api|login|logout) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

I would like to replace `(api|login|logout)` with some kind of catch-all. When I try to simply use `location / { ... }` though, nginx for some reason proxies through to my app instead of showing the static content. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with these `location` blocks:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```